# Python: Print all items in list in one statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

My current code loops through the `list` and prints items `i` and `i+1` next to each other. However, this results in code like:

```py
for i in list:
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(i+1))
```

This code works to print each item, but for project-related reasons they all need to be in one `print` statement, which would, if done manually, appear as:

```py
print(str(i) + ': ' + str(i+1) + '\n' + str(i+2) + ': ' + str(i+3) + '\n'...)
```

Which is absurd, and also does not use iteration to loop through the list, meaning it would have to be added to for each item in the list.

Therefore, my question is, how could this be done with recursion in this manner, where items `i` and `i+1` are printed, then items `i+2` and `i+3` on the next line in the same statement, and so on?

To elaborate on 'project-related reasons':
The project involves the Discord module, and it needs to export the information as one message sent in the channel. This means I cannot iterate through each and print it, as that would send a new message for each item in the list.

Comment: Can you explain why it has to be in one print statement? Can you create a string in a loop and then print that? Its hard for anyone here to give you a suggestion to work around such an arbitrary constraint without more information.

Comment: Note that's iteration, not recursion.

Comment: Your first code is not equivalent to your second code. Also, why don't you want to iterate over the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to not use `list` as a variable name! Secondly, you can write a generator function that runs through every second item in the list `arr` (starting either at 0 or 1) and `join` this to an empty string:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print( ''.join("{0}: {1}\n".format(i,k)  for i,k in zip(arr[0::2], arr[1::2])) )
```

This yields "items i and i+1 […] then items i+2 and i+3 on the next line", as requested :

```
1: 2
3: 4
5: 6
7: 8
```

Which is however different from your initial code, so perhaps you'd rather meant "items i and i+1 […], then items i+1 and i+2 on the next line :

```
print( ''.join("{0}: {1}\n".format(i,k)  for i,k in zip(arr[0:], arr[1:])) )
```

Comment: The first example works perfectly! Now I just have to figure out how it works so I can do it on my own next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
print(':'.join((str(i) for i in list)))
```

or this

```
print(''.join(( str(i)+(':'if not i%2 else '\n') for n,i in enumerate(list) )))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: @alec_a Change `list` to the name of a list. `'list` is a type.

Comment: This works, mostly. However, it uses `:` between each item in the list. Is there some way it could alternate using `':'` and `'\n'`?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator  check the second example for this

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want

```
list_value = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print('\n'.join(('{}: {}'.format(list_value[i],list_value[i+1]) for i in range(len(list_value)-1))))
```

Which gives:

```
a: b
b: c
c: d
d: e
```

Rather than the @user1438644 's answer of

```
print(':'.join((str(i) for i in list_value)))
```

which gives:

```
a:b:c:d:e
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would store your output in one string

```
output = ''

odd, even = mylist[::2], mylist[1::2]

for i in range(len(even)):
    output += '{}: {}\n'.format(odd[i], even[i])
print(output)
```

Comment: Except that it won't actually run, as `i` is the element of the list and `i+1` is that same element with an integer 1 added to it, not the next element

Comment: Thanks for point that out @macaw_9227. I've edited it to address this issue :)